# Count online user, daily and total visitors with firebase real-time database ( react typescript )

Tags: typescript, firebase

I'm trying to create an app which can count online, daily and total visitors to web page with real-time database of firebase but don't know how to start, any suggestion is appreciate, thank you

Comment: You can increment the active visitors value in db (although make sure you don't increment it twice for same user and so on). Not sure if you are interested in [Firebase Analytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Google Analytics for firebase](https://firebase.google.com/products/analytics) Which has a real-time dashboard for total visitor and much more interesting details, and it is free

If you are going to report it manually in the database it will be really expensive to do it for every single request and hackers can exploit it to incur your firebase billing.

Related Links: 
https://firebase.google.com/products/analytics 
https://firebase.google.com/pricing#realtime-database

Comment: i have followed your advice and implement react-ga package in my react app, now i can see data on google analytics dashboard but still don't know how to get that data from my app ( that means i can only write, and cannot read data ) can you help me with that

Comment: Try using the analytics reports api https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4

Comment: yeah i've tried that but the auth part made me confused, if i use an access token it will be unavailable after a while, then i found a solution:  service account from google cloud, as i know i can give permission to read data of google analytic to that account and call api from that account, but the difficult part is how to call api with that account, google give me a json file contain something like private key id and private key, and I don't know what to do with that json. Like with access token I can call api easily with postman, but with this json file i don't know what to do. thank you

Comment: Setup a cloud function to work as a api